Firth's model in R "missing values in resampled performance measures"
Here is an example with sample data
library(caret)
library(logistf)
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)

# Create a synthetic dataset
set.seed(123)
n <- 100
data <- data.table(
  predictor1 = rnorm(n),
  predictor2 = rnorm(n),
  predictor3 = rnorm(n),
  group = factor(sample(c("control", "AD"), n, replace = TRUE))
)

# Normalize the predictors
data_normalized <- as.data.table(scale(data[, .SD, .SDcols = -"group"]))
data_normalized[, group := data$group]

# Split into train and test sets
train_index <- createDataPartition(data_normalized$group, p = .75, list = FALSE)
train <- data_normalized[train_index, ]
test <- data_normalized[-train_index, ]

# Normalize training data
train_proc <- predict(preProcess(train, method = c("center", "scale"), verbose = TRUE), train)
train_proc[, group := factor(group, levels = c("control", "AD"))]

# Define training control
train_control <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", 
                              number = 3, repeats = 3,
                              savePredictions = TRUE,
                              classProbs = TRUE)

# Define the custom model function
firth_model <- list(
  type = "Classification",
  library = "logistf",
  loop = NULL,
  parameters = data.frame(parameter = c("none"), class = c("character"), label = c("none")),
  grid = function(x, y, len = NULL, search = "grid") {
    data.frame(none = "none")
  },
  fit = function(x, y, wts, param, lev, last, classProbs, ...) {
    data <- as.data.frame(x)
    data$group <- y
    logistf(group ~ ., data = data, control = logistf.control(maxit = 100), ...)
  },
  predict = function(modelFit, newdata, submodels = NULL) {
    as.factor(ifelse(predict(modelFit, newdata, type = "response") > 0.5, "AD", "control"))
  },
  prob = function(modelFit, newdata, submodels = NULL) {
    preds <- predict(modelFit, newdata, type = "response")
    data.frame(control = 1 - preds, AD = preds)
  }
)

# Training the model
set.seed(123)
firth.logist.model <- train(train_proc[, .SD, .SDcols = !c("group")],
                            train_proc$group,
                            method = firth_model,
                            trControl = train_control)

print(firth.logist.model)



received the following error:
> firth.logist.model <- train(train_proc[, .SD, .SDcols = !c("group")],
+                             train_proc$group,
+                             method = firth_model,
+                             trControl = train_control)
Something is wrong; all the Accuracy metric values are missing:
    Accuracy       Kappa    
 Min.   : NA   Min.   : NA  
 1st Qu.: NA   1st Qu.: NA  
 Median : NA   Median : NA  
 Mean   :NaN   Mean   :NaN  
 3rd Qu.: NA   3rd Qu.: NA  
 Max.   : NA   Max.   : NA  
 NA's   :1     NA's   :1    
Error: Stopping
In addition: Warning message:
In nominalTrainWorkflow(x = x, y = y, wts = weights, info = trainInfo,  :
  There were missing values in resampled performance measures.


I'm trying to compare performance across different models, when I use logistic regression or random forest from caret, the model all works (with the same training, cross validation, and test data), so not sure what's failing the Firth's model here.

Not reproducible. I get an accuracy of  0.4605128. I suggest quitting R and running the code again. I the error persists, upgrade R and the required packages.

Thank you! Indeed, restarting R solved the problem! PS: I tried restart r session many times, but it didn't help.
